# Firebase retrieve chid data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my object as follows

- -Notifications

  - userId

    - key1

      - datakey1

        - date: 10-10-2016
        - time: 3:20 pm
        - status: open
    - key2

      - datakey2

        - date: 11-10-2016
        - time: 5:00 pm
        - status: close

I'm having ref path till Notifications/userId

How do I retrieve data where status='open'

Code from comments:

```
ref.orderByChild("status")
   .equalTo('open')
   .on("value", function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.key); });
```

Comment: ref.orderByChild("status").equalTo('open').on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});

Answer (score 0):

Firebase queries can only contain one dynamic key.

In your case you have two dynamic keys under that `key1`/`key2` and `datakey1`/`datakey2`. You'll either have to put one of those at a fixed location (e.g. `key1/my/status`, `key2/my/status`) or you will have to structure your data differently.

```
notificationsStatusPerUser
    userId: {
      key1_datakey1: {
        status: "open",
        path: "key1/datakey1"
      }
      key2_datakey2: {
        status: "close",
        path: "key2/datakey2"
      }
    }
}
```

Now you can find all open items for a specific user with:

```
var query = ref.child('notificationsStatusPerUser')
               .child(uid)
               .orderByChild(status)
               .equalTo('open');
query.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    ref.child('notifications')
       .child(uid)
       .child(snapshot.val().path)
       .once('value', function(linkedSnapshot) {
           console.log(linkedSnapshot.val());
       });
};
```